# What are these threads named disk$0, disk$1, etc.?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphics, multithreading, htop

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The kernel version is 5.4.0-42.

Here is an example program:

```c
// mre.c
// Compile with: cc -o mre mre.c -lSDL2
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
int main(void)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO); // Doesn't work without SDL_INIT_VIDEO
    getchar();
}
```

When I look at the running program `./mre` in `htop` with thread names turned on, I see it has these four threads:

- `mre:disk$3`
- `mre:disk$2`
- `mre:disk$1`
- `mre:disk$0`

And here are some threads of `/usr/libexec/ibus-x11` with similar names:

- `ibus-x1:disk$3`
- `ibus-x1:disk$2`
- `ibus-x1:disk$1`
- `ibus-x1:disk$0`

Many programs don't have them (maybe they aren't using a certain graphical interface?)

Such threads always come in fours (my computer has four cores) and are listed in descending order. `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg` has eight of these threads, two of each number 0-3. What are they for?

Comment: Please relace screenshots with plain text encapsulated in ``` text ```

Comment: Can you point to the source code of your C++ program, or else provide some minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Is https://github.com/TurkeyMcMac/anosmellya your program? If yes, mention it in your question

Comment: I'm guessing the threads have something to due with using X11, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those threads are used for the [mesa disk cache](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Mesa-Disk-Cache-Quad-Core):

```
   util_queue_init(&cache->cache_queue, "disk$", 32, 4,
                   UTIL_QUEUE_INIT_RESIZE_IF_FULL |
                   UTIL_QUEUE_INIT_USE_MINIMUM_PRIORITY |
                   UTIL_QUEUE_INIT_SET_FULL_THREAD_AFFINITY);
```

https://sources.debian.org/src/mesa/22.0.3-1/src/util/disk_cache.c/?hl=174#L174

And inside `util_queue_init()` then:

```
   /* Form the thread name from process_name and name, limited to 13
    * characters. Characters 14-15 are reserved for the thread number.
    * Character 16 should be 0. Final form: "process:name12"
    *
    * If name is too long, it's truncated. If any space is left, the process
    * name fills it.
    */
```

https://sources.debian.org/src/mesa/22.0.3-1/src/util/u_queue.c/?hl=405#L414-L420

Thus, all GUI processes that somehow call into that mesa code create those extra threads, e.g. on a f33 desktop system of mine:

```
    pid     tid            comm cls
   1942    1989  gnome-s:disk$0 BAT 
   1942    1990  gnome-s:disk$1 BAT 
   1942    1991  gnome-s:disk$2 BAT 
   1942    1992  gnome-s:disk$3 BAT 
   2041    2237  Xwaylan:disk$0 BAT 
   2041    2238  Xwaylan:disk$1 BAT 
   2041    2239  Xwaylan:disk$2 BAT 
   2041    2240  Xwaylan:disk$3 BAT 
   2041    2259  Xwaylan:disk$0 BAT 
   2041    2260  Xwaylan:disk$1 BAT 
   2041    2261  Xwaylan:disk$2 BAT 
   2041    2262  Xwaylan:disk$3 BAT 
   2292    2325  gsd-xse:disk$0 BAT 
   2292    2326  gsd-xse:disk$1 BAT 
   2292    2327  gsd-xse:disk$2 BAT 
   2292    2328  gsd-xse:disk$3 BAT 
   2307    2344  ibus-x1:disk$0 BAT 
   2307    2345  ibus-x1:disk$1 BAT 
   2307    2346  ibus-x1:disk$2 BAT 
   2307    2347  ibus-x1:disk$3 BAT 
   2464    2578  firefox:disk$0 BAT 
   2464    2579  firefox:disk$1 BAT 
   2464    2580  firefox:disk$2 BAT 
   2464    2581  firefox:disk$3 BAT 
   2756    2785  firefox:disk$0 BAT 
   2756    2786  firefox:disk$1 BAT 
   2756    2787  firefox:disk$2 BAT 
   2756    2788  firefox:disk$3 BAT 
   2806    2841  firefox:disk$0 BAT 
   2806    2842  firefox:disk$1 BAT 
   2806    2843  firefox:disk$2 BAT 
   2806    2844  firefox:disk$3 BAT 
   2919    3078  firefox:disk$0 BAT 
   2919    3079  firefox:disk$1 BAT 
   2919    3080  firefox:disk$2 BAT 
   2919    3081  firefox:disk$3 BAT 
   3346    3367  firefox:disk$0 BAT 
   3346    3368  firefox:disk$1 BAT 
   3346    3369  firefox:disk$2 BAT 
   3346    3370  firefox:disk$3 BAT 
   3408    3426  firefox:disk$0 BAT 
   3408    3427  firefox:disk$1 BAT 
   3408    3428  firefox:disk$2 BAT 
   3408    3429  firefox:disk$3 BAT 
   5794    5825  firefox:disk$0 BAT 
   5794    5826  firefox:disk$1 BAT 
   5794    5827  firefox:disk$2 BAT 
   5794    5828  firefox:disk$3 BAT 
   6345    6364  firefox:disk$0 BAT 
   6345    6365  firefox:disk$1 BAT 
   6345    6366  firefox:disk$2 BAT 
   6345    6367  firefox:disk$3 BAT 
   9502    9525  firefox:disk$0 BAT 
   9502    9526  firefox:disk$1 BAT 
   9502    9527  firefox:disk$2 BAT 
   9502    9528  firefox:disk$3 BAT 
  22548   22565  firefox:disk$0 BAT 
  22548   22566  firefox:disk$1 BAT 
  22548   22567  firefox:disk$2 BAT 
  22548   22568  firefox:disk$3 BAT 
  33788   33807      vlc:disk$0 BAT 
  33788   33808      vlc:disk$1 BAT 
  33788   33809      vlc:disk$2 BAT 
  33788   33810      vlc:disk$3 BAT 
  48178   74574  kwallet:disk$0 BAT 
  48178   74575  kwallet:disk$1 BAT 
  48178   74576  kwallet:disk$2 BAT 
  48178   74577  kwallet:disk$3 BAT 
  60824   60830  chromiu:disk$0 BAT 
  60824   60831  chromiu:disk$1 BAT 
  60824   60832  chromiu:disk$2 BAT 
  60824   60833  chromiu:disk$3 BAT 
  69502   69519  firefox:disk$0 BAT 
  69502   69520  firefox:disk$1 BAT 
  69502   69521  firefox:disk$2 BAT 
  69502   69522  firefox:disk$3 BAT
```

Comment: Great info! Do the threads named *sh0*, *sh1*, *sh2* etc, also stem from Mesa? And what about *gdrv0* thread?

Comment: @Bram yes, the [sh threads](https://sources.debian.org/src/mesa/22.0.3-1/src/gallium/drivers/iris/iris_screen.c/?hl=902#L902) and [gdrv threads](https://sources.debian.org/src/mesa/22.0.3-1/src/gallium/auxiliary/util/u_threaded_context.c/?hl=4346#L4346) are also created by mesa.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, a C or C++ program can use [pthread_setname_np(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html) -using [prctl(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) system call- to change the thread name.

If the developer of your binary (or of a library used by your program, such as [libSDL](https://www.libsdl.org/)) decided to call that function, it usually succeeds.

You might use [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html), [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), [ltrace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) to investigate more. Or study the source code of [libSDL](https://www.libsdl.org/)

If you use the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, compile your C++ code [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` (and perhaps recompile [libSDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) from its source code, and at least study its source code since it is open source).